# Changing a sequence datatype from INT to BIGINT PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, integer, sqldatatypes, bigint

Hi I have PostgreSQL database with some values. When I created the tables, I didn’t pay much attention to their ID column. Now if I check the sequences, I see that the max value of some of them is of type int. How to change them to bigint without changing the IDs of the data. I changed the ID fields type in the tables from int to bigint. then
`ALTER SEQUENCE public.kvitansiya_id_seq MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807;` command returns an error such as

> SQL Error [22023]: ERROR: MAXVALUE (9223372036854775807) out of
> sequence data type (integer).

Here is photo of sequences tables on DBeaver.

[image]

Comment: Try this `ALTER SEQUENCE public.kvitansiya_id_seq as bigint MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thank you @akhilesh-mishra.
The solution

```
ALTER SEQUENCE public.kvitansiya_id_seq as bigint MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807;
```

was wonderfull.

Comment: FYI, the docs spell this out [ALTER SEQUENCE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altersequence.html) under 'data_type'.

Comment: Dear Adrian @adrian-klaver, you are right 100 percently. I didn’t notice or understand this in the documentation.

Comment: Do you really need the max value in your command, I tried 
ALTER SEQUENCE seq_name as bigint and it set the max value automatically to what you mentioned